# WPF MVVM Update source property only after user confirmation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am new to wpf and I have this situation. Let's say that I have a `Customer` model with `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Telephone` and so on. If the details of an existing customer needs to be edited, the `CustomerEdit` viewmodel is opened where it has a property of type `Customer`. The view has some textboxes bounded to `CurrentCustomer.FirstName` , `CurrentCustomer.LastName` and so on. Now whenever the user provided an input in those textboxes, the bounded property gets updated. There is a button for saving the changes done. Can there be some way to update source properties only when the save button is pressed, and if possible, in an MVVM way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply UpdateSourceTrigger Explicit like

```
<TextBox Name="itemNameTextBox"
         Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> "If you have a dialog or a user-editable form and you want to defer
>   source updates until the user is finished editing the fields and
>   clicks "OK", you can set the UpdateSourceTrigger value of your
>   bindings to Explicit"

MVVM Style:

If you want to do it in MVVM Style and if you have multiple textboxes then I suggest you to use a converter and create "Customer" object at there, which you can cast back easily in your VM. Handle the ICommand in your VM (Which will raised from your Button) and create CommandParameter by using Converter (textboxes values you can pass as an input to your converter).

Comment: Here's a detailed worked example: http://www.shujaat.net/2011/01/updatesourcetrigger-explicit-for-mvvm.html

Answer (score 7):

By default `Text` DP's, `UpdateSourceTrigger` value is `LostFocus`. Change it to `Explicit` and from save button click *manually update the source by getting binding expression* and calling `UpdateSource()` on it.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox"
         Text="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
<Button Click="btnSave_Click"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

---

Having this logic in code behind is not violating any MVVM rule but still if you don't want it in code behind. You can achieve this way:

Create an `ICommand` in your view model and ***bind to button command and in command parameter pass the text value of textBox***. You can either use `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` whichever suits your needs. For DelegateCommand refer to this [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html).

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox"
         Text="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=myTextBox}"/>
```

and in ViewModel command method set the actual value to which your textBox text is binded with.

```
private void SaveMethod(object parameter)
{
   this.PropertyName = parameter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i have seen this explicit way. but the thing I am looking for is how to update source after button pressed in an mvvm way. is there such an way? Perhaps I should edit my question.

Comment: This way you are `not violating any MVVM rule`. There is lot of misconception that `MVVM means No code behind`. As per MVVM, your code behind should not have any business logic, but it's completely fineto have UI logic in there. (That's what is code behind for).

Comment: @Victor - Updated with another approach without code behind.

Answer (score 1):

In MVVM scenario implement [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in `View-model` as explained and recommend in this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410405/1735196)

`IEditableObject` is a good interface anytime you want to be able to roll back changes.