# WPF best way to compare edited value and original value

Tags: c#, wpf, logic

Imagine that I have a textbox that bind to a value retrieved from database. And I have a cancel button.Something like below:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding [someViewModel].TestVar, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Now says `TestVar`'s value is 10 and when user updated the value and press the cancel button, I will show a popup to tell user that `your data will be lost. Are you sure you want to proceed?`

My idea is using either `TextChanged` or `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` to update a boolean flag and upon cancel button `onclick` do the checking. But the thing is if user updated the value first from 10 to 5, then back to 10? Then when user press the cancel button, there should be no alert message.

May I know what would be the most efficient way to achieve the objective?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Make a deep clone of your viewmodel and validate two integer values. See [How do you do a deep copy an object in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)
2. Make a `IntegerViewModel` with two fields

   ```
   // the value
   public int Value { get; set; }
   // the temporary backup value on edit.
   public int BackupValue { get; set; }
   ```

Comment: Wont it be heavy to store a copy of it just for a validation purpose?

Comment: If you want to avoid informessages after the value changes but has the old value again you have to know the old value. You can only know the old value if you save it. So you have to make a copy in any way. If it is just this one value I won't make a copy of viewmodels or extra viewmodels for primitive types. Then just store it in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

In MVVM scenario implement [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in `View-model` as explained and recommend in this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410405/1735196)

`IEditableObject` is a good interface anytime you want to be able to roll back changes.

Answer (score 0):

If You want only to know that the changes were perfomed, not exactly which property value changed into another etc. You can strore this information in a simple boolean flag like that:

```
private bool hasUnsavedChanges;

private string somePropertyValue;
public string SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.somePropertyValue;
    }

    set
    {
        if(this.somePropertyValue!= value)
        {
            this.hasUnsavedChanges = true;
        }

        this.somePropertyValue= value
    }
}
```

If You need to know everything about changes make a copying constructor of Your transfer object and store it in some backupCopy field. In validation method You just compare all required Properties of existing object and it's backup